# Strange if condition generated by Reflector

Tags: c#, .net, decompiling, reflector, .net-reflector

Every now and then I'll write a program to remind myself of something and so here's one I was writing yesterday when something strange happened.

**Original Source**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestThreadFunctions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main thread";

            var t = JoiningAnAlreadyCompletedThread();

            JoiningIsIdempotent(t);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static Thread JoiningAnAlreadyCompletedThread()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} ({Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}): I'm done now.\n");
            })
            { Name = "Worker 1" };

            t.Start();

            // Give a long time-out so we know that the 
            // current thread did not wait the entire time-out
            // or that it didn't wait at all because the thread
            // we are joining on has already completed.
            t.Join(10000);

            Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} ({Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}): I just joined on another thread that I knew was already completed even before I joined. See nothing happened. .NET doesn't punish you for joining a thread that has already completed, unlike POSIX systems, which do.\n");

            return t;
        }

        static void JoiningIsIdempotent(Thread threadToJoinOn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} ({Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}): I am about to join a thread that I already joined with earlier. I want to see if joining is idempotent.\n");

            // Joining is idempotent
            threadToJoinOn.Join();

            Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} ({Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}): I just finished joining with a thread that I already joined with earlier. See! nothing happened. Joining is idempotent.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

When I looked up the program in Reflector, it had this strange `if` condition at the beginning of the `JoiningAnAlreadyCompletedThread` method like so:

```
private static Thread JoiningAnAlreadyCompletedThread()
{
    if (<>c.<>9__1_0 == null)
    {
        ThreadStart start1 = <>c.<>9__1_0;
    }

    ...
}
```

I read it a couple of times just to confirm that I wasn't missing something. This is so strange it does nothing.

Just for the sake of completeness, here's the fully decompiled program from Reflector.

**Reflector Decompiled Source**

```
internal class Program
{
    // Methods
    private static Thread JoiningAnAlreadyCompletedThread()
    {
        if (<>c.<>9__1_0 == null)
        {
            ThreadStart start1 = <>c.<>9__1_0;
        }
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(<>c.<>9__1_0 = new ThreadStart(<>c.<>9.<JoiningAnAlreadyCompletedThread>b__1_0)) {
            Name = "Worker 1"
        };
        Thread t = thread1;
        t.Start();
        t.Join(0x2710);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1}): I just joined on another thread that I knew was already completed even before I joined. See nothing happened. .NET doesn't punish you for joining a thread that has already completed, unlike POSIX systems, which do.\n", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        return t;
    }

    private static void JoiningIsIdempotent(Thread threadToJoinOn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1}): I am about to join a thread that I already joined with earlier. I want to see if joining is idempotent.\n", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        threadToJoinOn.Join();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1}): I just finished joining with a thread that I already joined with earlier. See! nothing happened. Joining is idempotent.\n", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main thread";
        JoiningIsIdempotent(JoiningAnAlreadyCompletedThread());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    // Nested Types
    [Serializable, CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        // Fields
        public static readonly Program.<>c <>9 = new Program.<>c();
        public static ThreadStart <>9__1_0;

        // Methods
        internal void <JoiningAnAlreadyCompletedThread>b__1_0()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1}): I'm done now.\n", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        }
    }
}
```

I looked up the same source in IL Spy and it didn't do this weird thing. It did not have this strange `if` condition that did nothing.

**IL Spy Decompiled**

```
// TestThreadFunctions.Program
private static Thread JoiningAnAlreadyCompletedThread()
{
    ThreadStart arg_20_0;
    if ((arg_20_0 = Program.<>c.<>9__1_0) == null)
    {
        arg_20_0 = (Program.<>c.<>9__1_0 = new ThreadStart(Program.<>c.<>9.<JoiningAnAlreadyCompletedThread>b__1_0));
    }
    Thread thread = new Thread(arg_20_0)
    {
        Name = "Worker 1"
    };
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join(10000);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1}): I just joined on another thread that I knew was already completed even before I joined. See nothing happened. .NET doesn't punish you for joining a thread that has already completed, unlike POSIX systems, which do.\n", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    return thread;
}
```

So, I guess I don't know what the question here is. May be it is "why did Reflector do that?"

And then may be the answer is, "Well, decompilation is difficult," which I understand.

So, I really don't know what the question is but I guess I just wanted to share my bewilderment.

If you really see a question in here that has a plausible explanation, I'd love to know why Reflector did that.

Otherwise, I know this question is going to get downvoted and closed.

Comment: I can add that dnSpy is not doing that also https://d1ro8r1rbfn3jf.cloudfront.net/ms_125222/ejCTucEgvp3WFg11jkpEXMHgY4GvS3/dnSpy%2B3.0.1%2B%2528x64%2529%2B2017-05-13%2B12.30.03.png?Expires=1494750623&Signature=H~49usOzizNtpPm8YKECY6lgOpgJCEuQrjxYxlIQRR7y1qBeXXI4PM9wF9PFgHoHbZ2uLsXLDqynLdaUwrL9nO66340KU8djbt07g6FJAuKr4AN3Xb~cYQa3QE9t1O5-y-ouNmx79auMLWWAHA4C~MbVfbGXCOg6zuxLnqZDHXF6aMkKtBhYEa-i7l-yZIXxuZA-6vkqs22Hne4eBdeUHYQeyX8TpfzplzPdlJ9micPhL0HcNPVTm6iZXyTsDWOCBp~oWN31PkxfxG1higok1tHSxVQNgd6FaRna2EobYCehfib5Jlp12Dxcs2OswPlhtrWewX-qKk1~zy2QYTA3OQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJHEJJBIZWFB73RSA

Comment: Yay! Another open source decompiler.

Comment: The monikers for dnSpy and IL Spy are suspiciously similar. Must look up source to see if one is a fork of the other.

Comment: Telerik Decompile result is more readable and close to original http://imgur.com/a/yZQiM

Comment: Nice. So does dotPeek. It kind of shows the same source code we wrote with the filename as well. Don't know where it pulls that out from.